# EF 7 dnx database update command resulting in Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: architecture, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dnx, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to setup a project with a "Onion-like" structure where i use multiple layers for different parts of the project (DAL, BL, WEB). At first i had all my files in one single project, including the dependencies to EF where everything worked like a charm.

Then i began dividing up the different parts of the application and creating smaller projects for each "area".

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

I decided to break out entity framework from the top layer (wwwroot) and installing it's dependencies into my DAL project. EF runs fine and i can when i run the command

```
dnx ef migrations add somemigrationname
```

it adds the Migration folders into the DAL project and populates it with my desired migrations. Howerver, when i try to update my database using

```
dnx ef database update
```

it throws the following error:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

Of all the answers, regarding this error, i found here at stack overflow the majority pointed to an invalid connectionstring.

The weird part is that my connectionstring worked when i used ef and updated my database in the top layer (my wwwwroot project). But after i started using different layers it stopped working.

My DAL layer uses a own Startup file an dit looks like this:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {

        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
       services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<CustomContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<Entities.ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CustomContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
```

**EDIT:**
 My appsettings.json file inside my DAL project looks like this:

```
  {
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=customdb;User ID=Carl; Password=test; Integrated Security=false;"
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

One thing worth mentioning is that all my projects are only targeting dnxcore50{}, not dnx451 whatsoever.

Comment: Did you just test your connection string?

Comment: The connection string is identical to the one (which worked) I used before I moved EF into its own project.

Comment: ".\\Sqlexpress" seems weird to me as you prefix your string with @, I think it should be ".\Sqlexpress"

Comment: When i specify the connectionstring directly inside my Context class like:   `protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=customdb;User ID=username; Password=mypassword; Integrated Security=false;");
        }`   It works. **How do i make it work inside my startup.cs file inside my DAL project?** Is it possible?

Comment: Ok but this string is not prefixed by a @ : `"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=customdb;User ID=username; Password=mypassword; Integrated Security=false;"`, it's not : `@"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=customdb;User ID=username; Password=mypassword; Integrated Security=false;"` ! So, your  \\ represent a \\ and not a single \ when you use the @ prefix on a string.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info :) The weird part abuout this is that I read the connectionstring from my appsettings.json file inside the DAL project where the connection string looked like the one above (no @ symbol.) and it still didn't work.

Comment: How you do that ? Post your code and you appsettings file, It's another issue.

Comment: I've edited my question, there you can see how the connectionstring looks like inside my appsettings.json file and how it's being fetched by in the code. I'm not so sure one can have a own startup.cs file for a class library, maybe that's where the problem lives.

Comment: as I told you, your connection string is false, it should be : `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=customdb;User ID=username; Password=mypassword; Integrated Security=false;`

Comment: No, because with only one backslash dnx handles the .json file as invalid and is unable to parse it. So the .\\ is needed (inside the .json file). and in the startup.cs it throws the same error when I use .\ or .\\. So it has to be something else.

Comment: You said when you specify : `protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) { options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=customdb;User ID=username; Password=mypassword; Integrated Security=false;"); } ` it's work ! So, it's a single \

Answer (score 0):

You mistake is on your connection string:

```
var connection = @"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=customdb;User ID=username; Password=mypassword; Integrated Security=false;";
```

It must be :

```
var connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=customdb;User ID=username; Password=mypassword; Integrated Security=false;";
```

or

```
var connection = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=customdb;User ID=username; Password=mypassword; Integrated Security=false;";
```

if you don't want to use to use a verbatim string.

More on strings and vermatim strings in C#, read : [string (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)